# Java Netbeans code for IBM Watson Visual Recognition?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, visual-recognition

Respected All, I am new to learn IBM Watson for visual recognition and i have successfully created the visual recoginition model. I want to use this model from my form application for classifying images using that model.

I have searched a lot but i found differnt code segments and i am unable to do it because having less experience in development like this. Can any one give me full example code for java netbeans so that i can change with my credentials so that i will be able to use my model?

Comment: What code have you found so far? Have you come across https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk

Comment: I have cloned the above mentioned repository but i am unable to understand how to make configurations, dependencies etc. Can you recommend me some good material that shows how can i use that sdk for my own project step by step or any code sample. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know how to craft a REST service consumer using Java Netbeans? If not then you may need to rethink how you are going to approach this.